# SWT graphics color disappearing on selecting it on the TableViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt

I want to achieve something like this.

[image]

I'm able to display it on the `TableViewer` but when I select that item, the color disappears. I saw something like this in the Eclipse _Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The *Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts* page is implemented in the [`ColorsAndFontsPreferencePage`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/themes/ColorsAndFontsPreferencePage.java)

The colored rectangles are displayed by the label provider, an inner class named `PresentationLabelProvider`.

The label provider creates an image on the fly and uses a `GC` to draw a rectangle of the desired color.

Comment: Herrmann : My problem is like when ever I select the TableViewer cell, the color graphics is getting disappeared.

Comment: Then show us the code you use to display the color graphics.